# Sharing localhost with ipad over wifi

Tags: ipad, wifi, sharing

I really have no idea how to ask this, so with that have no idea where to search either. So.. I have a unique situation I think.

I have virtual box installed, with a local running server on it. I access it through my windows machine the host machine rather. via 127.0.0.1:3001. So I am here developing an app that can only be hosted on the virtual machine, as there are a lot of moving parts specific to  it that can't be hosted on a WAMP or even a typical web-server elsewhere. The vm OS is Ubuntu.  So here I am with a slight issue I want to see how this looks on my iPad, and a couple other tablets as the software being built into the VM is browser based as far as the GUI goes.

So theres the pretense. Heres the delima I want to use the built in browser on ipad to navigate to the browser based portion of my app on the VM like I can do through the Host machine. But Im not entirely sure how to achieve that. Its gotta be done over Wifi but what would I need to do to set that up accordingly?

Host Machine is Windows 7 Ultimate, VM is Ubuntu 10.x. This is not a screen sharing notion either. I don't want a to remote view the PC I want to type in the equivilant of 127.0.0.1:3001 into my ipad browser and view the service like I do vm to host machine.

Comment: Do you have another computer on the same WiFi network? Can you connect from there? I assume if it's working you will be using the host machine's local IP to access it. If it's working, you can use the same address in iPad. Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately currently I have a Mobile WiFi and my Laptop and my Ipad. I do have a shared network otherwise where PC's can link to one another and share. But for the sake of this I can't have a WAMP/LAMP on the local network as it will conflict with our existing in house servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change network virtual card on virtual machine parameters. You should select 'bridget' card insteat NAT or Host only. In this way virtual machine get a network IP and you can connect to this IP from your IPAD.

Comment: How could i find the IP of the VM?

Comment: helpful to a point I found a network ip based off of that. But for some reason still no go. Im thinking its something to do with configuring my ipad and win7 to work a little better cross the network its setup on but im not sure where to begin with that now

Answer (score 1):

Forward works great for things like this https://forwardhq.com/